# How to zero pad a matlab array?

Tags: matlab

What is the easiest way to (zero) pad a matlab array?
i.e. given `[1,2,3,4]` and length 6 return `[1,2,3,4,0,0]`

### Background

I have a data array which I would like to apply a windowing function to before running fft on the data.

I use to pass data directly to fft which would zero pad to the next power of 2, but now I need it zero padding before the fft so I can multiply by the window function.

```
fs = 100;                          % Sample frequency (Hz)
t = 0:1/fs:10-1/fs;                % 10 sec sample
x = (1.3)*sin(2*pi*15*t) ...       % 15 Hz component
  + (1.7)*sin(2*pi*40*(t-2)) ...   % 40 Hz component
  + (2.5)*randn(size(t));          % Gaussian noise;

m = length(x);          % Window length
n = pow2(nextpow2(m));  % Transform length
w = barthannwin( n );   % FFT Window

y = fft(data, n);       % DFT

windowed_data = x*w ; % Dimensions do not match as x not padded
y = fft(windowed_data, n); % DFT
```

I am aware of [padarray](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/padarray.html) as part of the Image Processing Toolbox, which I do not have.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT**

This method is probably even better for vectors as it does not break when they are transposed, note that it will change the original vector which may not be desirable:

```
myVec = 1:7;
myVec(end+3)=0
```

Alternately you can just concatenate zeros and the vector that you have and create a new variable with it.

```
myVec = 1:7;
requiredpadding = 10-7;
myVecPadded=[myVec zeros(1,requiredpadding)]
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no built in function to do padding, but here is a little function to pad vector `x` given a minimum length `n`.

```
function y = pad(x, n)
y = x;
if length(x) < n
    y(n) = 0;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

this should pad it with zeros to the nearest power of 2 for an array `a`:

`a(2^ceil(log2(length(a))))=0;`

Comment: It appears you forgot to remove the `end:` so i fixed that for you.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't realize MATLAB would just fill unspecified array indices with zeros.

Comment: @ZZZ - what if the original length of `a` is a power of 2? I suspect, in that case you would overwrite the last element!

Answer (score 0):

The image-processing toolbox of Matlab has a built-in function to pad arrays `padarray(A,dim,value`

For your example:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4];
dimension = [0 1]; % pad with extra columns
size = 2; % how much to pad
B = padarray(A,size*dimension,'post') % 'post' says to pad at the end
% just for demonstration, let's pre-pad the first dimension (rows)
dimension = [1 0];
C = padarray(A,dimension,'pre') % just as an example
% or pad in both directions
dimension = [1 2];
D = padarray(A,dimension) % by default, it will pad both pre and post
```

returns

```
B =

 1     2     3     4     0     0

C =

 0     0     0     0
 1     2     3     4
D =

 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     2     3     4     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

You can also use this for multi-dimensional arrays, the dimension vector just needs to be extended correspondingly, i.e. `dimension = [0 0 1]` will extend in the 3rd dimension.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I believe this part of a toolbox, not built -in.

Comment: You're right, my bad. It's part of the image-processing toolbox.